# How do Lua syntax rules differ between REPL and scripts?

Tags: lua, lua-5.3

I rarely use Lua so this might be a trivial question but I just noticed that with Lua 5.3.2, in the interactive REPL I can write for example:

```
> 1 == 2 or error('numbers not equal')
```

Which is how I'd perform error handling in Bash or Perl (or course the statement to the left of the `or` would be something more useful in real code, e.g. two variables).

But if I paste `1 == 2 or error('numbers not equal')` into some file `foo.lua` and then execute `lua foo.lua` this results in `lua: foo.lua:1: unexpected symbol near '1'`.

I can accept that this is invalid syntax but I find it very strange that the REPL would accept this statement nevertheless. Can someone explain what is going on here? Are to some general rules as to what I can do in the REPL that I can't do in a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lua REPL tries to evaluates input as expressions.(*) If it succeeds, it prints the results. This is for convenience only.

(*) It does that by prepending `return` to the input and trying to run that as a script.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense. Thank you.